# Have javac call automatically run java

Tags: java, interpreters, compilation

I want to be able to call `javac <class file name>`, and then automatically run java on the compiled `.class` file.

I thought initially to use a x86 disassembler to hack it (javac.exe) but bumped that idea; I then found the open source code for JDK, and concluded that maybe a batch file would be easier. How can I do this?

Comment: Batch file sounds good to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: consider studying tutorials on [Java CLI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) and [javac cmd line usage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html). Also, there are plenty tools that do stuff like that - just search web for stuff like Ant, Maven, Ivy, Gradle etc etc etc

Comment: Also note that for most non-trivial projects the class you compile is most likely not the one you want to run.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation/tool issue but is too old to migrate to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

It would probably be easier to use a build tool, like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). You could have a target to compile, a target to run your tests, a target to run, and so forth. You can set up different dependencies between them (for example, always make test clean your build files and compile before running).

Alternatively, a shell script would be the next best bet. However, that would be far less portable than something like Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run this as a process from within another Java process or from the Shell ?

If its from within a Java process,take a look at the [Processbuilder API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: I really appreciate and comend your help, but I think I will just use an IDE... I had to just use the command line for a lab for school. I don't HAVE to use it from the command line after using it to get the feel for it. Thanks however.